# Visual Studio Basic - convert string to list

Tags: string, vb.net, list

Converting string with delimiter to list.

I have a problem converting a string to a list of strings.

The only functionality I can find, is split to array.
But I want it to split to a list of strings.

Example string: "Date ;Lab. nr. ;Type ;"

I would like the outcome as a list:

Date

Lab. nr.

Type

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Would you mind marking my answer as accepted - click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.  You can also upvote answers if you feel they are helpful by clicking on the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Using `;` as your delimiter and `strExample` as your input string, you can use:

```
Dim strExample as String = "Date ;Lab. nr. ;Type ;"

    Dim lstSplit As List(Of String) =
          strExample.Split(New Char() {";"c},
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()
```

You can then iterate through your list as required:

```
For Each word As String In lstSplit
   word = word.Trim
Next
```

A good resource to learn how to split string using VB .NET is here:
https://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet